# Drawing bounding boxes through a live feed

Tags: c++, opencv, live-streaming, bounding-box

I was recently assigned a school project to do some filtering on a live video feed. The Idea is that only the biggest object currently in camera view is shown, I am planning to do this through the use of bounding boxes (deleting all objects except for the biggest one).

However I have very limited coding experience with C++ & opencv, so Im basically just picking code off the net where I can and (attempting to) editing it to fit my purpose.

At the moment I have attempted to combine the bounding boxes tutorial code found here :http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html

And this code right here (to greyscale each frame caught from the camera) without any success (probably because its horrible).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void thresh_callback(int, void* );

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    Mat edges;
    namedWindow("edges",1);
     cout << "Hello Application\n" << endl;
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame, GBlur;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        cvtColor(frame, edges, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        GBlur : GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
        Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
        imshow("edges", edges);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
   return(0);
```

If you guys have any advice on how I should go about this then please tell! Im kind of in a desperate mood lol.

Comment: GBlur : GaussianBlur looks weird. does it even compile ? did you mean cv::GaussianBlur ? (would make sense)

Comment: [the next steps](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html#find-contours) would be [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours), and to get the largest, filter them by [contourArea](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea)

Comment: @berak Yeah the declaration of Gblur as mat is kind of unnecessary, it did compile and run both with and without it. And yeah findContours has been applied in the bounding boxes section, but honestly I just have no clue how do apply those effects on the images of a live feed, I just cant get it to work.

Comment: you probably need to update the code above then.